# How come dpkg-deb: error: <file.deb>' is not a Debian binary archive (try dpkg-split?)

Tags: linux, debian

It is useful to have a .deb format file to supply users of ones programs.
The official way of creating as .deb archive via an upstream program, gpg authentication, quilt and debhelper is far too involved, because it is geared towards a chain of trust to be accepted in a distribution.
Suppose you have found a .deb archive but installing it gives an error.
How to resolve the error " is not a Debian binary archive" if you can assume the archive is realtively simple?

Comment: This is not a duplicate for the other question about dpkg-deb. In the first place it is for a binary archive, and the answers is instructive, not restricted to "bad archive, booh!" The other question could be a dplicate from this, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

The .deb archive is an archive created by ar in linux.
This archive contains the following files **in that order**

- debian-binary
- control.tar.xz
- data.tar.xz

debian-binary contains "2.0"

control.tar contains control and md5sums

data.tar contains your programs in a directory tree that is a copy of linux directory tree.

The error mentionned is a show stopper, because it gives no clue what happens.
After you have managed those three files in order, you can proceed :

```
lintian <file>.deb
```

The messages that come from lintian are much more helpful.